# iPhone 6S restores apps to freshly installed state for no reason

Tags: applications, iphone

I'm facing a weird problem with my 6S 64 gig device running iOS 9.3.2 (with no problems for over a month now). Multiple apps have their data reset to a freshly-installed like state without any reason. I'd open an app and see that it shows me the welcome screen and initial setup, much like you'd see when you installed the app.

I've seen WhatsApp, my bank app and Outlook go haywire. WhatsApp has done this multiple times now. I haven't reinstalled the apps or reset my phone yet, because I wanted to check online first if anyone else has encountered this situation, and if so, how they have resolved it.

Similar problems, anyone?

Comment: Do you have your iPhone setup to allow apps to be updated automatically in the background?

Comment: @fbara Yes I do. But none of these apps were updated in the past week.

Comment: @fbara I checked again - looks like I don't have that option enabled. I remember disabling it so I could stop updates that change stuff I like and also because I like reading changelogs.